# Adding "properties" to objects in a Blender scene

Tags: blender

I am just starting my dive into Blender coming mainly from Quake's Radiant. I am trying to research whether it will fit the need I have for a level editor replacement. So with that in mind, here is my question:

What is the best method for creating and storing a set of prefab "entity" objects such as health packs, ammo pickups, and "moveable" objects such that they have a set of "properties" that can be changed within Blender?

I have found this page, but I am still getting lost as to how to integrate them on a per object basis and achieve the desired result:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/properties_editor.html

*Note: It is not my goal to use the Blender game engine - just attach values to things for me to export to my own engine.*

**Edit1: Found an article discussing the topic although it seems very outdated:
https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/IwanGabovitch/20120524/171032/Using_Blender_3D_as_a_3d_map_editor_rather_than_programming_your_own_from_scratch.php**

Example:

```
// entity 105
{
"inv_item" "2"
"inv_name" "#str_02917"
"classname" "item_medkit"
"name" "item_medkit_11"
"origin" "-150 2322 72"
"triggerFirst" "1"
"triggersize" "40"
"rotation" "0.224951 0.97437 0 -0.97437 0.224951 0 0 0 1"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we can manually add [custom properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/custom_properties.html) to any object, these are added to the specific object so can be unique to each object.

A better way of integrating new properties is to use [bpy.props](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html), these can be added to an objects class in blender, this means every object will have the same properties available.

You can setup a [custom panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html) to edit your properties, like this [simple example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46294/935). Both the properties and panel as well as your object exporter can be defined in [an addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html) which you can have enable at startup so that it is available every time you run blender. An addon also makes it easier for you to share your game editor with others.

Comment: Pretty much my answer, but with some added details and docs. : )

Answer (score -1):

The link I found seems to be the best option and allow for the most flexibility. The source code for the Super Tux Kart plugins serve as a great reference implementation:

https://sourceforge.net/p/supertuxkart/code/HEAD/tree/media/trunk/blender_26/